# Run multiple Regressions with one button

Tags: excel, vba

I have potentially 3-16 regressions that need to be plotted at the same time.

Currently I have 16 buttons that each need to be clicked to plot; first, second, etc... This is obviously time consuming and I would like to make it so one button will run all the macro's. Two issues I have is I can't just have a but call Macro1, Macro2, etc... Also, I may only have 3 values to be plotted so I need the button to recognize how many points there are, and to plot accordingly.

Below is my first point, the other 15 are identical except for ranges:

```
Sub Macro1()
' Macro1 Macro
    Dim n As Range
    Set n = Worksheets("Data Input & Summary").Range("D67")
    If Range("D14") <> 0 Then
    Call Pre
     Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", Worksheets("analysis 1").Range(Range("F6"), Range("F6").End(xlDown).Offset(-n)), _
        Worksheets("analysis 1").Range(Range("G6"), Range("G6").End(xlDown).Offset(-n)), False, False, 90, Worksheets("Regression").Range("$A$1") _
        , False, False, False, False, , False
    Call Post
    Else
    MsgBox "You do not have any points to plot.", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT:** The Pre() and Post() functions are strictly unlocking and un-hiding sheets to plot the values and re-locking.

**EDIT 2:** This is probably whacked but it's my attempt at doing a loop, purpose is to help clear up any confusion with my goal.

```
Sub Regression()
    Dim n As Range, i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, m As Integer, o As Integer
    If Range("B14") <> 0 Then
    For o = 0 To ("B14") ' B14 is number of regressions to perform
        For i = 4 To 19 Step 1
            For j = 6 To 81 Step 4   ' Skipping 3 letters between
                For k = 7 To 82 Step 4  ' Skipping 3 letters between
                    For m = 1 To 346 Step 23 ' Skipping every 23 numbers
                        Set n = Worksheets("Data Input & Summary").Range(Cells(67, i))
                            Call Pre
                                Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", Worksheets("analysis 1").Range(Range(Cells(6, j)), Range(Cells(6, j)).End(xlDown).Offset(-n)), _
                                Worksheets("analysis 1").Range(Range(Cells(6, k)), Range(Cells(6, k)).End(xlDown).Offset(-n)), False, False, 90, Worksheets("Regression").Range(Cells(a, 1)) _
                                , False, False, False, False, , False
    Next m, k, j, i, o
    Call Post
    Else
    MsgBox "You do not have any points to plot.", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You want to make a loop first, to check what exactly you need to plot. So I suggest something like checking if the first cell of the range is empty with: If Cell(x,y).value = "" then

Comment: I suppose I could have a countif function hidden on the sheet to grab the amount of regressions to run. I am still fuzzy on how to go about incorporating that into running regressions one after another.

Comment: No need to have that in a WS function, you can just code it in. Works just as efficient.

Comment: Please elaborate in your question: What ranges need to be checked to contain values in order to determine which regressions need to be plotted. Are regressions always plotted in logical order, ie. 1,2,3,4,5 or can it be random: 1,5,8,13,16?

Comment: So every 4th and 5th letter will be the range, in my example above it's F6 and G6. Next would be K6, L6, then P6, Q6, and so on. Also it should be posted every 23rd row starting at A1, then A24, A47, etc...

Comment: I know it's difficult to understand, I would like it to be plotted in logical order. As what I was saying before I already have a number in my sheet represent the number of points (CountIf). So if it reads 7, I could use that cell (B14) to tell the macro to plot regressions 1-7.

Comment: Would being able to call the other buttons click events help you? If you needed to you could also create a form of what regressions to run so the right events are called. e.g. UserForm2.CommandButton1.Object.Value = True

Comment: Well calling didn't work for me since running the regression takes a second or two. I think I am getting somewhere with my attempt that I've edited into the OP. Am I on the right track for a loop?

Comment: Well it looks horrible, but does it work?

Comment: Edit #2 is what it has evolved into, I think I am getting closer but still no luck. I get a type mismatch error?